# How to enable a method only if two types are std::complex or not?

Tags: c++, enable-if

In a templated class I'd like to enable a function only if a class type and the methods type are std::complex or if both are not complex.

```
template<typename T>
class M {
public:
   template<typename T2>
   void method(T2 arg) { }
};
```

I'd like to the enable method only if T and T2 are std::complex or if both are not std::complex.

I found [How to identifying whether a template argument is std::complex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438493/how-to-identifying-whether-a-template-argument-is-stdcomplex) to get a template telling me how to check whether a type is std::complex-based or not. But I'm struggling with the formulation of the template-usage to use `std::enable_if`. I tried something with `std::is_same`, I haven't found how to do it. Then there is a way where you get the return-type from within std::enable_if, but again it didn't work as expected.

Comment: you want to require both `T1` and `T2` to be some `std::complex<U1>` and `std::complex<U2>` ? And only if thats the case, the method should be present?

Comment: Yes. I updated my question

Comment: yeah got it, supposed you have a trait `is_complex` you want `is_complex<T> == is_complex<T2>`

Comment: yes, I tried this in an enable_if, but I couldn't make it work. Lack of knowledge of how to use std::enable_if.

Answer (score 2):

You can deduce template arguments:

```
 template<typename T2>
 void method(std::complex<T2> arg) { }
```

A more complete example:

**[Live On Coliru](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/rfq6aq7ej)**

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class M {
    public:
      template <typename T2> void method(T2 const&) const {
          std::cout << "Primary template " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
      }

      template <typename U> void method(std::complex<U> const&) const = delete;
};

template <typename V> class M<std::complex<V> > {
    public:
      void method(std::complex<V> const&) const {
          std::cout << "Specialization " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
      }
};

int main() {
    {
        M<std::pair<int, double> > m;
        m.method(std::string("hello"));
        m.method(3.1415926);
    }
    {
        M<std::complex<double> > m;
        // m.method(std::string("hello")); // doesn't compile, not std::complex
        m.method(3.1415926);
    }
}
```

Printing

```
Primary template void M<T>::method(const T2&) const [with T2 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; T = std::pair<int, double>]
Primary template void M<T>::method(const T2&) const [with T2 = double; T = std::pair<int, double>]
Specialization void M<std::complex<_Tp> >::method(const std::complex<_Tp>&) const [with V = double]
```

Comment: Not sure how this answers my question.

Comment: Maybe I missed the problem? I included a more complete example to highlight how I think it answers your question:

Comment: The problem with this is if you have a lot of methods in your generic template that you want added to your specialized one. I'm not sure what's the original intent though, and maybe a different design is in order for the class proposed in the question itself.

Comment: It is possible to (partially) specialize specific members instead of the entire class, too.

Comment: True, but then I think we go to a solution closer to 463...'s enable_if, and I think both are good solutions.

Comment: @kabanus True enough! If the question had added more context I'd whip up a more realistic example. But right now that feels like... imagining complexity that may not even match OP's situation.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I did not consider implicit conversions, because you asked for `T2` to be `std::complex`. See at the end for what I mean.

You can write a trait to detect if some type is an instantiation of `std::complex`. Then you can use `std::enable_if` for return type SFINAE:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <complex>

template <typename T>
struct is_complex : std::false_type {};

template <typename U>
struct is_complex< std::complex<U> > : std::true_type {};



template<typename T>
class M {
public:
   template<typename T2>
   std::enable_if_t<is_complex<T>::value == is_complex<T2>::value> method(T2 arg) { }
};
```

`std::enable_if_t< condition >` is `void` when the condition is `true` and a substitution failure otherwise.

---

Implicit converions:

The above only works when `T2` is deduced to be some instantiation of `std::complex`. So far so good. But it does not work when you call the method with some argument that can implicitly be converted to a `std::complex`. For example:

```
 struct foo {
     operator std::complex<double>() { return {}; }
 };

 int main() {
     M<std::complex<double>> m;
     foo f;
     std::complex<double> c = f;   // OK !
     m.method(f);                  // fails :/
 }
```

This is somewhat unexpected unless you delibaretly want to disable implicit conversion. For a solution that does allow for implicit conversions see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77369388/4117728).

---

PS: There is a proposal to add a `std::is_complex`: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2078r0.pdf. I just found it and don't know what happened to it. In my opinion, its not something that we need in the standard library, because next we will have `is_vector`, `is_map` and `is_unordered_map` and `is_foo` and `is_bar`.

Comment: This kinda prevents usual overloading because implicit conversion are not considered

Comment: @sehe not sure what you mean. `T2 arg` matches anything (but then it is removed from the overload set when the condition OP asked for does not hold)

Comment: @sehe oh ok, you mean conversion from some type to `std::complex<U>` ? I didnt consider it because its also not covered by OPs method

Comment: It is though, because OP's takes by value and implicit conversions apply. But yeah I meant this (https://compiler-explorer.com/z/j8438xbW8) - bit late but why throw away the sample :)

Comment: @sehe it took me a while to see that after your edit your answer is the right one. I think I will delete this ...

Comment: I'd keep yours for instructional value. After all it demonstrates the /expected/ technique, whereas I side-stepped it with specialization - which seems more natural to me given the goal

Comment: hm right. I'll add a note on the conversions

Comment: Actually see my comment on Sehe's answer - this provides functionality the other question cannot (as written).